# Small perturbations of embedded submanifold is still embedded

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I was reading Lee's Riemannian manifold book,in page 239,we have the following procedure to perturb the embedded submanifold:

Let $M\subset \tilde{M}$ be the embedded Riemann submanifold,locally we can choose a Fermi coordinate,for $\tilde{M}$ as $(\tilde{U},(x_1,...,x_n,v))$ ,with slice $U = M\cap\tilde{U}$,then we can pick a smooth function with compact support in $U$  denote it $\varphi$ perturb $M$ in $\tilde{U}$ into $$\{z\in \tilde{U}\mid v(z) = t\varphi(x^1(z),...,x^n(z))\}$$ for some small $t$.

The question is how to prove that the manifold after the perturbation is still  embedded submanifold?We need to use the graph of smooth map is embedded in product manifold,but I don't know how to make it precise?

Comment: I have a idea now,just prove the result in Eucleadin space,then map back to manifold using diffeomorphism .

Comment: In fact this is the general fact that "embedding  is stable under small perturbation" see Guillemin and Pollack Differential topology  p35